# Parsing variable column length in R

Tags: r, csv, data-analysis

I have a text file which is comma separated and has 50 rows. The first 10 lines have 6 columns and next 10 lines have 8 columns and so on. In short different rows may have different columns. 
How do I read it using R? I tried using `read.table()` but it is reading the data all wrong.

Also there is a unique identifier column which will say how many columns this row will have.

Comment: Have you tried read.csv() or read.csv2() ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think if you would provide a few lines of the file and show what you'd like as a result, you might not get those downvotes.

Comment: Agreed..please always make your question reproducible..search SO for reproducible code in R. I didnt downvote too.

Answer (score 2):

Just read your data using `fill=TRUE` flag of `read.table`. This automatically adds blanks in case of unequal columns

data

```
A,B
C,D,E,G
H,I,J

read.table(data,sep=",",fill=TRUE)
```

output

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  B      
2  C  D  E  G
3  H  I  J
```

Comment: Simplified the answer